# Remove space from last column in comma separated csv file using batch

Tags: csv, batch-file

This script removes space from all columns

```
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set in=f1.csv
Set out=f2.csv
For /f "tokens=* delims=," %%A in ('type %in%') do set line=%%A
>>%out% echo !line: =!
)
```

Input:"a,b c d,e "
Actual:"a,bcd,e"
Expected:"a,b c d,e"

I want to remove space from last column only.

Comment: Fascinating.  Thanks for sharing.  Did you have a question?  (Pro tip: edit your post.  Include expected behavior vs. actual behavior.)

Comment: And the question is ????

Comment: PowerShell has powerful support for processing CSVs (see `Import-CSV` and `Export-CSV`). Is that an option, or are you firmly wedded to batch?

Comment: is the csv with fixed number of columnns?

Comment: You might have edited your post, but it still does not contain a specific question...

Comment: Rtrim will do the job, http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#Function.rTrim

Comment: If all lines end with a space character and the CSV file was created with a batch file containing `echo ... >>f1.csv` then I suggest to avoid appending a space to end of each line by removing the space left of `>>` or using `>>f1.csv echo ...`.

Answer (score 1):

`!line: =!` removes all spaces from the `!line!` variable, which is why you end up with `a,bcd,e`.

If you only want to remove a *single trailing space* from the entire line, you could do it this way:

```
>>%out% echo !line:~0,-1!
```

If you want to remove spaces in some columns and leave spaces in other columns, you'll have to handle each one separately.

```
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%A in ('type %in%') do (
    set "colA=%%A"
    set "colB=%%B"
    set "colC=%%C"
    >>%out% echo !colA!,!colB!,!colC: =!
)
```

This will, however, still remove *all* spaces from the last column.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
>>%out% echo !line: =!
```

insert these lines:

```
if "!line:~-1"==" " set "line=!line:~0,-1"
>>%out% echo !line!
```

(if the last character is a space, remove the last character)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution.  It should work with CSV files with an unknown number of columns (up to 20 as it is, but you can increase the number in the `for /L` loop at the expense of a little efficiency).  I use a bunch of `call` statements when setting variables to avoid squashing exclamation marks in the column values.

```js
@echo off & setlocal

rem // redirect output to new csv file
>"new.csv" (

    rem // get each line from the old csv file
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("test.csv") do (
        set "line=%%I"

        rem // get the last column (max 20 columns)
        call set "last=%%line:*,=%%"
        for /L %%# in (1,1,19) do call set "last=%%last:*,=%%"

        rem // remove spaces in last column and reassemble line
        call call set "line=%%%%line:%%last%%=%%last: =%%%%%%"

        rem // output result
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Bear in mind that this will give incorrect results if your right-most CSV column contains quoted commas, or if the value of another column is identical to the value of the last column.

Addressing [@RB's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795468/remove-space-from-last-column-in-comma-separated-csv-file-using-batch#comment61166637_36795468): not having a header row in the CSV file makes parsing with PowerShell a little more complicated than one might expect.  It's still safer than attempting to split on commas, though.  Here's a batch + PowerShell hybrid script that demonstrates.

```perl
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

set "csvfile=test.csv"
>"new.csv" powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"

goto :EOF
: end batch / begin PowerShell hybrid code #>

# because csv is headerless, specify generic header row (max 20 cols)
$csv = import-csv $env:csvfile -header (1..20)

# check which columns have data
$cols = $csv | gm | ?{
    $_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty' -and $_.Definition -match '^string'
} | %{ $_.Name }

# for each row...
for ($i=0; $i -lt $csv.length; $i++) {

    # copy meaningful column values into temporary array
    $output = @()
    foreach ($col in $cols) { $output += $csv[$i].$col }

    # replace spaces in the last element
    $output[$output.length-1] = $output[$output.length-1] -replace " "

    # output the result
    $output -join ","
}
```